# Nautilus 3.6 - look for filenames in current directory before general search

Tags: nautilus, 13.04

Is there a way to set the new Nautilus in Ubuntu 13.04 to have an old behaviour I liked, namely:

- Type something
- An item matching that name will be selected (pretty much like using the Tab key in a terminal)

This used to be virtually instant and quite convenient, but now it does a deep search across a variety of parameters when you start typing.

The deep search is useful, but by far the more frequent task is to select something within the current directory by name, which the old function satisfied perfectly.

Is there a way to restore this behaviour? I couldn't find an option in Preferences.

If possible, I'd like to avoid a roll-back as I hate to fight progress, but if that's the only option I'll take it.

Comment: The  nautilus search in 3.6+ does start @ the current dir & also will recursively searche any sub dir in that dir. It works quite well & is far superior to previous nautilus search. What you're missing is type ahead find, it's gone & at the moment no indication it will be returned or replaced

Comment: @doug Sad face! Certainly the new search is superior at searching, but doesn't have the snappy performance of type ahead find. I suspect that an analysis of use cases and user experience would reveal that type ahead find was the more commonly intended operation.

Answer (score 6):

Nautilus 3.6+ has removed or changed many good features it had in older versions; One is the typical search you mentioned. You have two options, one is to change your file browser from nautilus to "**nemo**" or something similar; another is to use non-official patched nautilus, named "[SolusOS](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/install-solusos-patched-nautilus-in-ubuntu-1204.html)".